# Error en SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando borrar datos de una tabla, pero cada vez que abro la aplicacion y le doy al boton de eliminar se me para y me sale de la aplicacion creo que es en el `SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();`

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TAG = DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DB_NAME = "myapp.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String USER_TABLE = "users";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_usurarios = "usurarios";
public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";

/*
create table users(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    usurarios text,
    password text);
 */
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_usurarios + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT);";

public DbHelper(Context applicationContext, Object o, Context context, int i) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String usurarios, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_usurarios, usurarios);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

    long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Usuario insertado" + id);
}





public boolean getUser(String usurarios, String pass){
    //HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
            COLUMN_usurarios + " = " + "'"+usurarios+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'"+pass+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        return true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return false;
}

public String eliminar(String usuarios){
    String mensaje="";

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    int cantidad = db.delete("myapp.db","usuarios='"+usuarios+"'",null);

    if(cantidad!=0){
        mensaje="eliminado correctamente";
    }else{
        mensaje="No existe";
    }

    return mensaje;
}
public ArrayList llenar_lv(){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM datos";
    Cursor registros = database.rawQuery(q,null);
    if(registros.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            lista.add(registros.getString(1));
        }while(registros.moveToNext());
    }
    return lista;

}
```

}

Este es el metodo eliminar

```
public String eliminar(String usuarios){
    String mensaje="";

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    int cantidad = db.delete("myapp.db","usuarios='"+usuarios+"'",null);

    if(cantidad!=0){
        mensaje="eliminado correctamente";
    }else{
        mensaje="No existe";
    }

    return mensaje;
}
```

Errores del LogCat

```
11-24 01:49:21.333 6797-6797/com.techobbyist.signuplogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                           at com.techobbyist.signuplogin.DbHelper.eliminar(DbHelper.java:94)
                                                                           at com.techobbyist.signuplogin.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:47)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error :

```
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
```

Aparece cuando le estas pasando un contexto **null** a tu constructor.

y para :

```
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
```

Es por que usas `getWritableDatabase()` usas mas de una vez sin cerrar la anterior sesion de la BD.

Para Cerrar la sesión de la BD debes usar `db.close();` en la función eliminar, después de realizar la acción `delete()`

```
public String eliminar(String usuarios){
    String mensaje="";

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    int cantidad = db.delete("myapp.db","usuarios='"+usuarios+"'",null);

    if(cantidad!=0){
        mensaje="eliminado correctamente";
    }else{
        mensaje="No existe";
    }
    db.close(); // esto va aqui
    return mensaje;
}
```

Y en tu botón debes instanciar la bd y llamar a la función eliminar()

```
private Datahelper mydb; //intancia

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    mydb =new Datahelper(getActivity()); //contexto
```

Comment: Hola Ashley muchas gracias por su respuesta, ¿Y como puedo mejorar el constructor? ¿Que tengo que poner? muchas gracias

Comment: Respuesta actualizada @zzxbx

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que el método para eliminar **[delete()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))** requiere como primer parámetro, la tabla en la cual realizara la eliminación de los datos.

```
public int delete(String tabla, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
```

tu estas definiendo el nombre de la base de datos lo cual es incorrecto:

```
int cantidad = db.delete("myapp.db","usuarios='"+usuarios+"'",null);
```

**Debes definir el nombre de la tabla**, no el de la base de datos, además revisa la documentación para definir correctamente como eliminar:

```
int cantidad = db.delete(USER_TABLE,"usuarios = ?", new String[]{usuarios});
```

Comment: Hola jorge muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero me sigue dando error

Comment: Probablemente tienes otros errores, agrega el mensaje de error en el LogCat es importante

Comment: Como puedo agregar el LogCat

Comment: en la documentación https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html , el query completo en realidad esta incorrecto debe ser int cantidad = db.delete(USER_TABLE,"usuarios = ?", new String[]{usuarios}); revisa la actualización

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado pero el LogCat me señala que el error es en SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase(); y luego tengo otro error pero en otra clase que llama al metodo eliminar String mensaje = db.eliminar(usuarios);

Comment: Entonces tienes varios problemas, el error que comentas SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase(); puede ser por permisos, agrega lo que muestra el LogCat. Que sistema operativo tiene tu dispositivo?

Comment: Es un samsung galaxy SIII version 4.3 android.

Comment: Esto es lo que me dice en el LogCat

Comment: at com.techobbyist.signuplogin.DbHelper.eliminar(DbHelper.java:94)
                                                                                 at com.techobbyist.signuplogin.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:47)

Comment: agrega la información a tu pregunta, agrega también la parte donde indique "Caused by ......"

Comment: ya esta actualizado